# How to define supported screen resolutions for an android game in unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-games, pixel-perfect

I have a pixel art game that looks good at the reference resolution 480x800 pixels (use of pixel perfect camera) and any resolution bigger than that it will look ok with some blurring (i don't know if it's a problem or that how it works while scaled up) but for any resolution lower than that the pixels will look disorted , is there an option to prevent players with lower resolution mobile from downloading this game from google play ?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of locking out users from playing your game I think a better approach would be to look at some other options first.

You can set a reference resolution on the canvas in which your sprites reside, and set "UI scale mode" to "Constant pixel size" instead of "Scale with screen size" this way your sprites will always be in the resolution you want them to be, instead of getting stretched/compressed.

Create multiple quality levels: By having your images in multiple resolutions you can choose which quality option should be used for which quality setting.

If you still insist on excluding devices from downloading you game that is also an option. Google play store allows for you to exclude devices from downloading your application. You can do this under the "Release management > Device catalog." tab on your google console. For a more thorough explenation on this see the [official documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7353455?hl=en)

Comment: the problem of resolution is not for ui elements but for in game sprites , thanks for the trick below

Comment: Have you tried setting the "Pixels per Unit" of the sprites instead? this dictates how the pixels scale according to one world unit. Meaning you can create a constant sprite size over multiple resolutions with this instead.

Comment: yes i did , some sprites have disorted pixels in small resolutions , i took 400x800 cause i need more view in my game , my sprites are different in thier sizes 56 to 57 pixels in height , ppu i set it to 128 and it looks good for a 400x800 resolutions and more n except a weird problem i found it now a sprite from my sprites is disorted in a samsung core prime and looks good in an old samsung trend lite even that they have the same resolution 400x800

Answer (score 1):

I know there is how, but I don't think this is the correct approach. Come to think of it: you are deliberately **excluding** a portion of your audience from playing for simply not having a target resolution.

This is not how it's supposed to go. Limitations should be about hardware (and even so, there are some workarounds). I'd advise your to create different arts for each resolution you will provide support for, and then disclosing the fact that the art might be off in not supported resolutions somewhere in the game or the app page.

Comment: thanks for ur advice , but i think making multiple sprites is a hard way